# Find a basis of nullspace(A)

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}4&-4&2&-6\\2&-2&1&-3\end{bmatrix}$ Find a basis of **nullspace**$(A)$

I first put $A$ in RREF to get: $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1/2&-3/2\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I then found that $x_1 = 1x_2 - \frac{1}{2}x_3 + \frac{3}{2}x_4$

I then got $x_2 \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_3 \begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_4 \begin{bmatrix}3/2\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

For some reason my online homework program is saying I am incorrect and that the answer should be:

$\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0\\-3\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$ What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your basis is not exactly correct: $$\pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} = \pmatrix{x_2-\frac 12x_3+\frac 32x_4 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4} =\ \ ?$$

Comment: $x_2 \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_3 \begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_4 \begin{bmatrix}3/2\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Now your first is correct, but the second and third vectors are still wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is correct or not, but keep in mind that there's not a unique answer to this question, there is always more than one basis for any given space.

Comment: @Bye_World I see what I did wrong now, I forgot that it was $(1)x_1$ which then puts a 1 in my first position then I have the pivots that follow which is the 1 below which i forgot and had them in the wrong positioning: $x_2 \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_3 \begin{bmatrix}-1/2\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}, x_4 \begin{bmatrix}3/2\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Shammy OK.  Now answer this (to yourself): what do you get when you multiply your first vector by $2$?  What about when you add your first vector and twice your second?  Continuing in that way hopefully you'll see that both bases in fact describe the same space.

Comment: Oh yes @Bye_World I get that part, I get that there are infinitely many solutions as well. I'm confused tho, I just got $1$ pivot in RREF form, why then does the basis of nullspace(a) consist of 3 sets? I understand why each vector has four rows because we have four variables respectively. But why do we have 3 sets? we have 1 pivot so shouldnt we have 1 set?

Comment: Note that you would have gotten a scalar multiple of each of the vectors in your solution sheet's basis if you had taken the *second* variable as the dependent one.  Which is another perfectly valid thing to do.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that the procedure you've gone through to get your basis is completely standard (even if there are other procedures, e.g. solving for $x_2$ instead of $x_1$), and aside from scaling the vectors by something obvious to clear denominators (i.e. multiplying them by 2), I would expect a reasonable computer program to follow the same strategy as you and produce a basis that is more obviously connected to yours (i.e. differing only up to some scalings) as opposed to linear combinations.

Comment: You mean three **vectors**?  Because you have three free variables.

Comment: Ok so the vectors correspond to the number of free variables @Bye_World got it

Comment: and the rows correspond to the number of columns in the matrix that are non zero?

Comment: Dear @Shammy, You might try the linear algebra toolkit: http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi. It's user-friendly and follows standard conventions in e.g. computing nullspaces (to wit, its nullspace calculator, when fed your matrix, produces the basis you've written down). I've used it extensively to check computations when teaching linear algebra and it's never  given me anything unexpected.

Comment: Oh I get it now. $x_2 = x_2 = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first vector you got is missing the $1$ in the second entry, since it represents the $x_2$ free variable (this is equivalent to the first solution vector from the homework program). The $x_3$ vector should have a $-1/2$ in the first entry and a $1$ in the third entry. The $x_4$ vector should have a $3/2$ in the first entry, and a $1$ in the fourth entry. Your only problem is that you need to put a $1$ in the entry of the vector that corresponds to the free variable (e.g. the $x_2$ vector should have a $1$ in the second entry). The basis that was given to you as a homework answer is another basis that also works, however involves a slightly different approach, which may have been causing the confusion.